# Get the player with the highest score on the scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I get the player with the highest score on a scoreboard according to a player's kills in Minecraft? I have tried doing:

```
/tellraw @a[score_kill_min=1,team=Seekers] {text:"You won!"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for how many people have a positive kill count:

```
testfor @a[score_kill_min=1, team=Seekers]
```

If there is more than 1 person, then decrease everyone's kill count then test again:

```
scoreboard players remove @a kill 1
```

When there is only 1 person, give the message:

```
tellraw @a[score_kill_min=1,team=Seekers] {text:"You won!"}
```

You will also probably want to set everyone's kills back to 0:

```
scoreboard players set @a kill 0
```

Comment: The testfor command will output to a comparator the signal strength of the number of people, correct? (One person left would be one length of redstone wire output length)

Comment: @EliasBenevedes Yep.

Comment: @colorfusion How will I check when there is only one person left?

Comment: @user3189338 Put a comparator on the first command block. If the signal strength given out is 1, then there is only 1 player left.